# Getting the Swagger/OAS definition of the REST APIs

Tags: swagger, docusignapi

Quick and simple: Is it possible to get the complete OAS/YAML/JSON definition of these APIs? For example the ESIGN API.

I want import these definitions and generate a connector to do a low/zero coding implementation.
Thanks in advance.
AA

Comment: Thank you. Downloaded the .json file already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alejandro, you're in luck.
[DocuSign uses the OpenAPI (OAI)](https://github.com/docusign/eSign-OpenAPI-Specification) Specification - formerly known as "Swagger" - to describe its REST APIs. The goal of the OAI specification is to define a standard, language-agnostic interface to REST APIs which allows both humans and computers to discover and understand the capabilities of the service. For more info see the official [OAI spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification).

Comment: Thanks Inbar. Its interesting how these vendors take specs like OpenAPIs/Swagger but at the end create good-old-SOA-type assets. For example this DocuSign API contains hundreds of objects and methods. In fact more than 45000 lines of code. That makes this API virtually unusable, cumbersome and very difficult to reuse/share. Not only that but it also contain errors: Unresolved reference 'offlineAttributes' at (36534, 11) and Unresolved reference 'signHashDocument' at (22482, 13). Partition the APIs in Domains and using smaller subsets makes development and agility to use, much more efficient.